# Delete duplicate values in a row within a Pandas DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, duplicates, pandas

what is the expression to remove duplicate-values in any row within a pandas dataframe as follows....(note: first column is the index (date), followed by four columns of data).

1983-02-16  512 517 510 514,
1983-02-17  513 520 513 517,
1983-02-18  500 500 500 500  <-- duplicate values,
1983-02-21  505 505 496 496

Delete row of duplicate values, end up with this...

1983-02-16  512 517 510 514,
1983-02-17  513 520 513 517,
1983-02-21  505 505 496 496

Could only find how to do this by columns, not rows....Many thanks in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more elegant/dynamic (but perhaps less performant version):

```
In [11]: msk = df1.apply(lambda col: df[1] != col).any(axis=1)
Out[11]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

In [12]: msk.index = df1.index  # iloc doesn't support masking

In [13]: df1.loc[msk]
Out[13]:
              1    2    3    4
1983-02-16  512  517  510  514
1983-02-17  513  520  513  517
1983-02-21  505  505  496  496
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import io
content = '''\
1983-02-16 512 517 510 514
1983-02-17 513 520 513 517
1983-02-18 500 500 500 500
1983-02-21 505 505 496 496'''
df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), parse_dates=[0], header=None, sep='\s+',
                   index_col=0)
index = (df[1] == df[2]) & (df[1] == df[3]) & (df[1] == df[4])
df = df.ix[~index]
print(df)
```

yields

```
              1    2    3    4
0                             
1983-02-16  512  517  510  514
1983-02-17  513  520  513  517
1983-02-21  505  505  496  496
```

`df.ix` can be used to select rows. `df = df.ix[~index]` selects all rows where `index` is False.